# Plotting multiple lm() models in one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm, gam

I have fitted 6 `lm()` models and 1 `gam()` model on the same dataset.

Now I want to plot them all in one plot on top of each other. Can I do this without defining the models again in ggplot?

My case is this

I have

```
model1 <- lm(y~1, data = data) %>% coef()
model2 <- lm(y~x, data = data) %>% coef()
model3 <- lm(y~abs(x), data = data) %>% coef()
...
model7 <- gam(y~s(x), data = data) %>% coef()
```

can I feed the stored coefficients of my models to ggplot?

```
ggplot(data, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y)) +
geom_point() +
geom_abline(model1) +
geom_abline(model2) +
....
```

Or do Is the only way to plot the model prediction lines to manualy fill out the parameters like this:

```
ggplot(data, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y)) +  
  geom_point() +  
  geom_abline(intercept = model1[1]) +  
  geom_abline(slope = model2[2], intercept = model2[1]) +  
  geom_abline(slope = model3[2], intercept = model3[1]) +  
  ...
```

Example code

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(50)
y <- rweibull(50,1)
d <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
model1 <- coef(lm(y~1, data = d))
model2 <- coef(lm(y~x, data = d))
model3 <- coef(lm(y~abs(x), data = d))
```

Including the SE for each line/model and a legend would be welcome as well.

Comment: What do you want to plot from the lm object? e.g. what is an example of one of the sets of plots you want, with example code

Comment: Added more details. Can't see how I can give an example.. because I don't know the code?

Comment: We don't need an example of the plotting code, we need an example of the input data to the plots. We need code that we can copy/paste that will produce the `lm` and `gam` models that you want to plot (it doesn't have to be your real data, but it needs to be something we can actually run ourselves, not pseduocode). That way we can test possible solutions.

Comment: Would the new edit I did suffice?

Comment: Please some sample data so the models run. The example code is much better, but I'm confused why you are only saving the `coef()`, not the actual model. Up above you had a `gam` example, which obviously won't work well if you just save the `coef()`...

Comment: Two other things: (a) it's nice to `set.seed()` before doing random draws so we all get the same numbers. `set.seed(123)`. (b) Please be clearer about what you want---is it just the prediction lines? Or do you want confidence intervals too? Do you want to differentiate the lines by color, with a legend? Or you don't care about that?

Comment: I only saved the coef because I saw ggplot can take them as input. the ´gam()´ would indeed have been a different case, but I was confident that given a workflow for the others, I could work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for this to work, you really need to save the whole model. So if we assume you have the entire model

```
# set.seed(101) used for sample data
model1 <- lm(y~1, data = d)
model2 <- lm(y~x, data = d)
model3 <- lm(y~abs(x), data = d)
```

We can write a helper function to predict new values from these models over a the given range of x values. Here's such a function

```
newvalsforx <- function(x) {
  xrng <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out=100)
  function(m) data.frame(x=xrng, y=predict(m, data.frame(x=xrng)))
}
pred <- newvals(d$x)
```

This `pred()` will make predictions from the models over the observed range of `x`. We can then use these as new data to pass to geom_lines that we can add to a plot. For example

```
ggplot(d, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line(data=pred(model1), color="red") + 
  geom_line(data=pred(model2), color="blue") + 
  geom_line(data=pred(model3), color="green")
```

This gives me

[image: multi-predict plot]

Comment: I knew this was possible. But figured there might be an easier way by just giving ggplot the model object or the coefficients? Guess not then? Thanks a lot though!